# Confusion about unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, unrecognized-selector

Sooooo, I keep getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CardGameViewController matchModeSegmentedControl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c84da0'

I've been doing a bunch of Googling, but I'm pretty confused about what exactly the problem is. Here's all the code that contains anything involving the Segmented Control (the source of all my current woes).

```
@interface CardGameViewController ()
 ...
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *matchModeSegmentedControl;
 ...
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController
```

...

```
- (CardMatchingGame *)game
{
    self.matchModeSegmentedControl.enabled = YES;
    if (!_game) {
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc]
                 initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count]
                 withDeck:[self newPlayingCardDeck]
                 withSegmentedControllerValue:self.gameMatchMode];
    }
    return _game;
}
```

...

```
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.matchModeSegmentedControl.enabled = NO;
    int cardIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];
    Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:cardIndex];

    if (!card.isChosen) {
        [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:cardIndex];

        [self updateUI];
        [self.game compareSelectedCards:cardIndex];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateUI)
                   withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }
}
```

...

```
- (IBAction)matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    self.gameMatchMode = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [self.game setValueMatchMode:self.gameMatchMode];
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

EDIT:
Full stack trace below...sorry about the formatting. I just copied and pasted.

```
 2014-12-02 23:54:44.549 Matchismo[15252:60b] -[CardGameViewController
 matchModeSegmentedControl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
 0x8c454f0 (lldb) bt
 * thread #1: tid = 0x1a48c4, 0x015748b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread',
 stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x015748b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x01892243 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
frame #2: 0x017e550b CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1019
frame #3: 0x017e50ee CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 14
frame #4: 0x0158682b libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #5: 0x002363b9 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
frame #6: 0x00236345 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
frame #7: 0x00337bd1 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
frame #8: 0x00337fc6 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
frame #9: 0x00337c06 UIKit`-[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 48
frame #10: 0x003a6222 UIKit`-[UISegmentedControl _setSelectedSegmentIndex:notify:animate:] + 598
frame #11: 0x003a8573 UIKit`-[UISegmentedControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 175
frame #12: 0x00275ddd UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
frame #13: 0x002769d1 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
frame #14: 0x002485f2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
frame #15: 0x00232353 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
frame #16: 0x0177e77f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #17: 0x0177e10b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
frame #18: 0x0179b1ae CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 910
frame #19: 0x0179a9d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
frame #20: 0x0179a7eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #21: 0x037e95ee GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #22: 0x037e942b GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #23: 0x00234f9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
frame #24: 0x00003edd Matchismo`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffede4) + 141 at main.m:16 (lldb)
```

With an All Exceptions breakpoint, XCode directs me to this:

```
#import "CardGameAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding All Exceptions breakpoint and check call stack.

Comment: post the code from where you are calling this method. matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged

Comment: @OlegShulakov: call stack included in original post.

Comment: @Dev the method is called when the UISegmentedControl is touched during runtime, via an outlet or what-have-you (sorry I'm very new to iOS, I don't quite have all the lingo down yet!).

Comment: It means that CardGameViewController does not have a method named `matchModeSegmentedControl:`.  Usually this error occurs because you've used the wrong pointer type somewhere.

Comment: Note that in your case it's likely that you have a XIB element linked to your CardGameViewController when it's supposed to be linked to some sort of segment display controller.  Or perhaps your CardGameViewController is the delegate for a segment display and you failed to implement a delegate method.

Comment: You should send an object of type UISegmentedControl to this method matchModeSegmentedControl:. This crash is because of you sent some other object type to this method. Check what type of object you are sending to this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that something sent the message `-matchModeSegmentedControl:` to an instance of `CardGameViewController`. Note the colon on that message name.

Your class has a property `matchModeSegmentedControl` whose getter is a method named after the property (`-matchModeSegmentedControl`). Note, no colon in that method name.

Your class also has an action method named `-matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged:`. As is normal for action methods, that method takes an argument and thus has a colon. Also, the name is quite similar to the property.

I suspect you have connected a segmented control's action to the wrong action method (one which doesn't actually exist). It's trying to invoke an action named `-matchModeSegmentedControl:` when it should be invoking the action named `-matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged:`. That may have been set up in the NIB. Maybe you changed the name of the action method at some point but didn't update the connection in the NIB. The NIB should be showing you a warning, which I would expect would also appear when you build.

Comment: XCode doesn't give me any warnings, but it looks like you're onto something! I re-assigned the Segmented Control's outlet to the `-matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged:` method and magically the error disappeared. However, (admittedly this is a totally new question...) now the `-touchCardButton:` method fails to disable the Segmented Control. (Granted, this was of course also the case when the app was simply crashing...) Any idea where my code is messing up? Thanks!

Comment: An outlet is a property that holds a reference to an object in the NIB and which is connected to that object in the NIB. That's different from connecting a control's "sent action" connection to its target. Typically, you might have an outlet from a controller object to a segmented control and/or the segmented control would be configured to send its action to a target, but you would not have an "outlet" **from** the segmented controller.

Comment: I expect you want to connect the controller's `matchModeSegmentedControl` outlet to the segmented control and the segmented control's action to the `matchModeSegmentedControlIndexChanged:` action method on the target.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! That's what I really meant to say I did. (I don't quite have the lingo down yet. But that was an excellent explanation/clarification!)

Comment: If `-touchCardButton:` is still not updating the segmented control, then that suggests you haven't connected the controller's `matchModeSegmentedControl` outlet to the segmented control.

Comment: When I right-click the segmented control, it lists under Sent Events "Value Changed" - "Card Game View Controller matchModeSegmentedControllerIndexChanged:" and under Referencing Outlets "matchModeSegmentedControl" - "Card Game View Controller". I made the connections by ctrl-dragging the segmented control onto the property and the method... Did I do something wrong, or could it be something else? I feel like everything is right so far...

Comment: That sounds right. In `-touchCardButton:`, log the value of `self.matchModeSegmentedControl`.

Comment: Add a line like `NSLog(@"%@", self.matchModeSegmentedControl);` in `-touchCardButton:`. I'm trying to determine if the outlet is `nil`.

Comment: Done. `2014-12-03 21:34:01.580 Matchismo[15897:60b] <UISegmentedControl: 0x8e6c4d0; frame = (164 91; 136 29); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e6c570>>`

Comment: OK, so the outlet is connected properly. My next guess is that `-touchCardButton:` is, in fact, disabling the segmented controll, but something is re-enabling it. For example, I notice that the `-game` method enables it, and `-touchCardButton:` calls that. Put log statements everywhere that you set the `enabled` property of the segmented control and you'll probably see what is happening.

Comment: You, sir, are a debugging genius. I can't believe I missed something so obvious! The enabling statement was simply put in the wrong place, and I apparently failed to test it properly until now (although admittedly I was quite distracted by the initial error). A million thanks for walking me through this!!!